# Код продолжает работать после ошибки 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: php, runtime

Бот не возвращает заголовков, но продолжжает работать. Так я выполняю очень долгий скрипт, и работает стабильно. Так и должно быть??

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Kiev');
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "shumik", "***", "****");
$timestart = microtime(true);
sleep(100);
function run_my_last(){ 
    global $mysqli, $timestart;
    $res = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `**` SET `value` = 'wait' WHERE `param` LIKE 'queue_cron_status'");
    $res = $mysqli->query("UPDATE `**` SET `value` = '".(microtime(true) - $timestart)."' WHERE `param` LIKE 'time_query'");
}
register_shutdown_function('run_my_last');
```

В базу записывает число 100, и ровно после 40 с. после того как в браузере выбило ошибку 504 Gateway Time-out (на 60-ой секунде).

В предыдущем посте мне сказали, что все функции и процессы полностью останавливаються

Comment: У каждого компонента «цепи» есть свои ограничения по времени - у браузера, делающего запрос, у веб сервера, обслуживающего этот запрос, у скрипта, запускающегося веб сервером, у сервера БД, и так далее. В вашем случае у браузера оказался самый короткий лимит по времени, но это не значит что так оно происходит и так и будет всегда и во всех случаях.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, и правда. Посмотрел phpinfo - времени достаточно много)